# Working with TimeSpan in U-SQL

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

Assume that I have a database with the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    start DateTime,
    end DateTime,
    activityId Guid,
    level string,
    INDEX Table1 CLUSTERED(start ASC) PARTITIONED BY HASH(level)
);
```

And I'd like to get the duration of each activity, so I try to run the following code:

```
@result = SELECT activityId, level, (end - start) AS duration
          FROM Table;
```

The column `duration` is being outputted in the correct "TimeSpan" format (e.g. "00:00:00.0123").

However, if I try to perform calculations on that columns, such as AVG/MAX/etc, I'm getting an error saying that TimeSpan cannot be used as a column type.

Answer (score 2):

TimeSpan is not a supported built-in type. TimeSpan is basically a long, so you can convert it into a long and then perform your operations and at the end, cast it back.

In the future we will be adding support for User-defined types. In that case you can either wrap it into a UDT or implement the serialization interface that you will need to provide.

If you would like us to add TimeSpan as a built-in type, please file a request at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/suggestions/13123272-support-columns-of-type-timespan

Comment: I added the suggestion. Using UDT might be problematic for me, since I'm generating the USQL statement by code from a different query language, making things complicated, and making the conversions almost impossible.

Comment: Thanks for filing the feedback item!